# React.js using Parent's function to control Child's state

Tags: reactjs

I want to use parent's function to control child's state

so I code these in my parent.jsx

```
changeFilter(){
if(this.state.imgFilter=='none'){
  this.setState({
    imgFilter:'imgFilter',dataFilter:1
  },()=>this.selectFood)
}
else if(this.state.imgFilter=='imgFilter'){
  this.setState({
    imgFilter:'none',dataFilter:0
  },()=>this.selectFood)
}

}
```

but I want to let this in parent.jsx be this in child.js

how could I do that?

Comment: React only has one way data flow. The parent can pass information to its children through props but there's no direct way of passing information from the children to the parent. One way to get around this is to use callbacks. You can pass a callback from the parent to the child which the child will call to indicate some change in its state. From your question, it isn't clear if this is what you want though.

Answer (score 1):

The parent component

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child filter={this.state.imgFilter} toggleFilter={this._toggleFilter} />
      </div>
    )
  }

  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      imgFilter: "none",
    }

    this._toggleFilter = this._toggleFilter.bind(this)
  }

  _toggleFilter() {
    this.setState(state => {
      return {
        imgFilter: state.imgFilter === "imgFilter" ? "none" : "imgFilter",
      }      
    })
  }
}
```

Notes

- line 1: Change Parent to your parent's component name
- line 2: Stylistic to put render() first. Most put
  constructor() first
- line 5: highly recommend caching your functions rather than inlining
  them into your render function. this avoids recreating the function on
  re-renders
- line 10-11: only need props in constructor()/super() if using inside
  the constructor()
- line 17: binding your function's this
- line 20: js convention to put underscore in front of method/function
  that's local
- line 21: recommend functional setState(). stricter ordering of state
  mutations to aid reproducibility. object-style setState(), the
  default, is async and can update state out of order
- line 23: convention prefers having "none" as the fallback clause,
  ordering the ternary this way to keep in line with your original post

The child component

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    // imgFilter && toggleFilter() are accessible from this.props
    // this.props.imgFilter
    // this.props.toggleFilter()
    // e.g. <div onClick={this.props.toggleFilter()}></div>

    return <div></div>
  }
}
```

Comment: You should add an explanation of why this is the correct approach.